# Creating Typescript definition files from module.exports = js files

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I am trying to create a Typescript definition file for [format-duration](https://github.com/ungoldman/format-duration):

```
module.exports = (ms) => {
  let { days, hours, minutes, seconds } = parseMs(ms)
  seconds = addZero(seconds)
  if (days) return `${days}:${addZero(hours)}:${addZero(minutes)}:${seconds}`
  if (hours) return `${hours}:${addZero(minutes)}:${seconds}`
  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`
}
```

I have tried a few different declaration files:

```
export default function (ms: number): string;

export default function formatDuration(ms: number): string;

export function formatDuration(ms: number): string;
```

and whilst I do get the correct type information from them when I run the application I get an error:

```
import formatDuration from "format-duration";

const formatted = formatDuration(123456);
```

`Exception has occurred: TypeError
TypeError: format_duration_1.default is not a function`

How do I properly define types for this sort of javascript library?

Comment: Which one of the export statements give you the half output?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to type a nameless export? In the other cases you should be able to use `declare formatDuration:(ms:number):string`

Comment: You should read this first -https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the correct declaration file looks like this:

```
declare function formatDuration(ms: number): string;

export = formatDuration;
```

and it is imported like this:

```
import formatDuration = require("format-duration");
```